# How to refactor getIntent() code to use parseUri() instead?

Tags: java, android

According to [`getIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getIntent(java.lang.String)) documentation, the method was deprecated in Android API 15. Instead, we are recommended to "Use [`parseUri(String, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#parseUri(java.lang.String,%20int)) instead." and to "Call `parseUri(String, int)` with 0 flags."

This advice is kind of confusing since `getIntent` could be called without arguments. For example, here is a code snippet from a [Udacity course exercise](https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/tree/student/Lesson04a-Starting-New-Activities/T04a.03-Solution-PassingDataBetweenActivities/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/explicitintent) using the old API:

MainActivity.java

```
/*
 * Here, we create the Intent that will start the Activity we specified above in
 * the destinationActivity variable. The constructor for an Intent also requires a
 * context, which we stored in the variable named "context".
 */
Intent startChildActivityIntent = new Intent(context, destinationActivity);

/*
 * We use the putExtra method of the Intent class to pass some extra stuff to the
 * Activity that we are starting. Generally, this data is quite simple, such as
 * a String or a number. However, there are ways to pass more complex objects.
 */
startChildActivityIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textEntered);

/*
 * Once the Intent has been created, we can use Activity's method, "startActivity"
 * to start the ChildActivity.
 */
startActivity(startChildActivityIntent);
```

ChildActivity.java

```
/*
 * Here is where all the magic happens. The getIntent method will give us the Intent that
 * started this particular Activity.
 */
Intent intentThatStartedThisActivity = getIntent();
```

How would I refactor ChildActivity.java to use `parseUri` instead of `getIntent`?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong method/docs. That `getIntent()` is in the `Activity` class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getIntent(). That said, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Oh! Thanks actually that answers my question.